# Fetching Publishing Pages from Pages Library in SharePoint 2010 ECMAScript OM

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

i want to fetch all the pages in a specific Publishing Web using JavaScript and Client Object Model, it keeps giving

> The property or field has not been initialized. It has not been requested or the request has not been executed. It may need to be explicitly requested.

Here's the code,

```
 var selectedDoc;
    var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var site = ctx.get_site();
        //('created ctx');
        //loading the Library 
        var pagesLib = site.openWeb('/Ar/News').get_lists().getByTitle('Pages');

        if (missionType == 'All') {

            var query = new SP.CamlQuery();

            query.set_viewXml("<View><RowLimit>10</RowLimit></View>");
       selectedDoc = pagesLib.getItems(query);

            ctx.load(selectedDoc,'Include(Title)');

            ctx.executeQueryAsync(getAllNewsWithQuerySuccess(this,this.onListLoadSuccess), getAllNewsWithQueryFailure(this,this.onQueryFailed));
```

Answer (score 1):

You might be missing a `load` call. Try this right after you assign `pagesLib`:

```
ctx.load(pagesLib);
```

I'm guessing the error is due to `pagesLib` not having been populated before you execute the CAML query against it.

Comment: Thanks, checked it but with no luck, i ended up using Server Side code to generate the Markup that is needed for the JQuery plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You might be missing a load call. Try this right after you assign pagesLib:

```
ctx.load(pagesLib);
```

I'm guessing the error is due to pagesLib not having been populated before you execute the CAML query against it.